# Warning: Invalid value for prop `dispatch` on <span> tag

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've read blog about new changes (where is describing about such warning), so I have a question: what is the right way to write pure components which is not used any action?

Here is a sample with this error

```
const Text = ({
    tagName = 'span',
    className = '',
    children = null,
    ...restProps
}) => {
    const Tag = tagName;

    return (
        <Tag {...restProps} className={className}>
            {children}
        </Tag>
    );
};

Text.defaultProps = {
    tagName: 'span',
    className: '',
    children: null,
};

export default Text;
```

If I use connect to connect Text to the store - I will have this error because I have nothing to write in mapDispatchToProps function and according to docs:
"If you do not supply your own mapDispatchToProps function or object full of action creators, the default mapDispatchToProps implementation just injects dispatch into your component’s props."

so I have a choise:

```
to declare dispatch in props in dumb component and omit it in params in Text rendering
to write fake mapDispatchToProps function in connect
```

which variant is the more desirable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not spreading dispatch from props passing to `Tag`

```
const Text = ({
    tagName = 'span',
    className = '',
    children = null,
    dispatch,
    ...restProps
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have asked about a choise:to spread dispatch in props  description or inject fake mapDispatchToProps to not inject dispatch into props

Comment: Thanks! I imported dispatch from props and it resolved the warning `const { dispatch, ...other } = this.props;`. Yet I didn't invoke `dispatch` anywhere, wonder why it works...I am using redux `mapStateToProps` and I think it's related?

Comment: same issue here, if you destruct dispatch, children components will not be able to use it anymore?

Comment: Are you able to explain the sentence in your post with a different wording? What are you saying the OP is not doing?

Answer (score 4):

We have to pass a noop (`() => {}`) in order to not pass `dispatch` to the connected component.

Other option might be some kind of a props mapper, e.g. [recompose's mapProps](https://recompose.docsforhumans.com/api/mapprops.html).